# Iframe com meu domínio como source não carrega. Como resolver isto?

Tags: url, iframe

Coloquei o iframe `<iframe src="http://axitech.com.br"></iframe>` num arquivo html dentro do próprio domínio e depois coloquei dentro de outro domínio. O resultado é que minha url não carrega em nenhum dos domínios que eu testei.

De passagem, a url do Google também não carrega ( `<iframe src="http://google.com.br"></iframe>` ). O sistema na url ***axitech*** é Wordpress.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

[**URL de teste**](http://mvnp.com.br/themes.php) funciona.

[**URL de teste**](http://mvnp.com.br/index.php) não funciona.

Comment: A URL http://axitech.com.br não tem nenhum conteúdo, nem quando chamada direto no endereço do navegador. Na verdade o iframe carregou sem erros com esse endereço. Já o Google dá o erro: `Refused to display 'https://www.google.com.br/?gws_rd=ssl' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

Comment: Coloquei a url certa no item NÃO FUNCIONA.

Comment: Agora sim, mesmo erro do google. Refused to display 'http://z12.axitech.com.br/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não vai ser possível exibir a página que você que pois o servidor no qual ela está hospedada está enviando o seguinte *header*:

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Enquanto esse *header* estiver sendo enviado, não vai ser possível usá-la num iframe. Se você tem contato com quem administra o site, pode pedir para adicionarem:

```
ALLOW-FROM uri
```

Onde uri seria a sua página que teria permissão para utilizar o iframe.

Leia mais sobre X-Frame-Options em:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options